# Untrack and stop tracking files in git

Tags: git

I have a deep subfolder called `objects` with files called `*.object` which I don't want tracked by git (Windows).

In .gitignore I have tried various combinations (e.g. `**/objects/*` or `**/objects/*` etc.) to no avail: each time, when I do `git status` I see:

```
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       foo/src/objects/a.object
#       foo/src/objects/b.object
```

It is only when I add `*.object` to .gitignore that the files disappear from the untracked files list. What's wrong with my wild cards?

Also, when is `git update-index` required and when should I do `git rm --cached myfile`?

Is there a wildcard feature for rm like `git rm --cached **/foo/*.zip`?

UPDATE: Similarly, adding the line `.gitignore` to `.gitignore` (not always desirable but still) has no effect. Is this weirdness because the files may have been tracked in the past?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

OK, though wildcards don't work (in Windows apparently) it seems one can remove a whole folder with:

```
git rm -r --cached "path/to/foo/"
```

I understand that --cached only unstages - you have to `git commit` to remove them from the repo.

Comment: I presume you have to add the file/directory to .gitignore too.

Comment: fatal: pathspec  did not match any files